# Email Validation (React Native). Returning the result as 'invalid' for all the entries

Tags: javascript, validation, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to validate a users email, by checking it against an expression. But the result i am getting is invalid for all the entries.

**UPDATED CODE**

```
class dummytest extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
                email :'',
                validated: false ,
                 }
  };

go = () => {
           const reg = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
           if (reg.test(this.state.email) === true){
               alert( valid);
           }
           else{
               alert();
           }
 }
  render(){
       return(
         <View style={{alignSelf:'center',marginTop:100}}>
              <TextInput autoCapitalize="none" autoCorrect={false} style={{height:20,width:200,backgroundColor:'blue'}} value={this.setState.email}/>

              <Button onPress={this.go.bind(this)}>
                 <Text> GO </Text>
              </Button>
          </View>

       );
    }
}
```

Comment: you are actually doing it opposite.. it is `const reg = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/` then `if (reg.test(this.state.email) == true)` for positive response

Comment: That regular expression won't my e-mail address anyway...

Comment: @robertklep is it wrong?

Comment: @NeelGala I am sorry, but it is giving invalid for all the entries. I don't think it is accepting the if condition.

Comment: @AvikritKhati yes, look [here](http://emailregex.com/).

Comment: @robertklep it worked. Even i used for the javascript

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Ok I got the code working, below you can take the look for validating the email on each user input :

1. Your function part:

```js
validate = (text) => {
  console.log(text);
  let reg = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w\w+)+$/;
  if (reg.test(text) === false) {
    console.log("Email is Not Correct");
    this.setState({ email: text })
    return false;
  }
  else {
    this.setState({ email: text })
    console.log("Email is Correct");
  }
}
```

2. You TextInput Component:

```js
<TextInput
  placeholder="Email ID"
  onChangeText={(text) => this.validate(text)}
  value={this.state.email}
/>
```

Comment: so if i had to validate the email after i pressed a button. What should i change.

Comment: call the `this.validate(text)` from onPress of button. and test the value from the state

Comment: i am sorry i don't understand the last part. Could you show me how?

Comment: In validate function : `validate = () => {let text = this.state.email ....}`onPress of Button. and rest will be same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142953/discussion-between-avikrit-khati-and-neel-gala).

Comment: why you are setState if not a valid email? @NeelGala

Comment: beware that the regex only matches traditional top level domains, such as ".com" or ".de", but not something (new) like ".berlin" or ".shop". The `.\w{2,3}` at the end needs to be something like `.\w{2,}`. For a more sophisticated regex, see
https://emailregex.com/

Comment: this allow `@gmail.comdfsfs`   :(

Answer (score 4):

There is an easy to validate an email without writing a lot of code, by using a npm package called ***validator***

1. Installation

   ```sh
   npm i validator
   ```
2. Import the package

   ```js
   const validator = require('validator');
   ```
3. Use it to verify the email

   ```
   validator.isEmail('john.doe@example.com');    // true
   ```

For more information, see the documentation:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator

Comment: how do you use that from with React Native? This is NodeJS code - not React Native code

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a syntax error. You've got a nested function called `validate` directly inside the definition for `go`.

As a general rule I would suggest to keep your indentation and curly-brackets consistent so these sort of errors are detectable at a glance-- when the brackets don't line up there's a problem.

Then, there's a few things you might do to get this code working:

- Remove the `validate (email)` line along with its accompanying close
  bracket
- Reference email via this.state.email in `go`
- Add an additional state variable to indicate if the email has been
  validated or not.

Something like:

```
this.state = {
 email :'',
 validated : false,
}
```

And...

```
go = () => {  
        if (this.state.email.test(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/)==0) {
            this.setState({ validated : true });
        } else {
            this.setState({ validated : false });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But how do i send the value  of email from `<TextInput>` to the go function

Comment: i get an error `_this.state.email.test is not a function`. it is undefined it says.

Comment: could you please help me out?

Comment: Most likely because this is referencing the Button and not your class. If you change the prop to onPress={this.go.bind(this)} that should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

`if you use hooks, you can try as this`

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [emailValidError, setEmailValidError] = useState('');
```

`when user enter  email this function will call`

```
const handleValidEmail = val => {
let reg = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w\w+)+$/;

if (val.length === 0) {
  setEmailValidError('email address must be enter');
} else if (reg.test(val) === false) {
  setEmailValidError('enter valid email address');
} else if (reg.test(val) === true) {
  setEmailValidError('');
}
};


 <TextInput
    style={styles.input}
    placeholder="Email"
    value={email}
    autoCorrect={false}
    autoCapitalize="none"
    onChangeText={value => {
      setEmail(value);
      handleValidEmail(value);
    }}
  />
```

`enter this line bellow input field`

```
{emailValidError ? <Text>{emailValidError}</Text> : null}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created a Helper class and doing like this:

```
export default class Helper {

     static isEmailValid(email) {
        let reg = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
        return reg.test(email) == 0;
   }
}
```

Call this method by:

```
if (Helper.isEmailValid(this.state.emailText)) {
    console.log("Email is correct");
} else {
    console.log("Email is not correct");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
validate = (text) => {
console.log(text);
let reg = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/ ;
if(reg.test(text) === false)
{
alert("Email is Not Correct");
this.setState({email:text})
return false;
  }
else {
  this.setState({email:text})
  alert("Email is Correct");
}
}


You can put this function validate in onChangeText propert of TextInput
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Having a function that validates the email (probably in some separate module as you are going to reuse it),

```
export function validateIsEmail(email) {
  return /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email);
}
```

You can validate email input,

Live validation:

```
        <TextInput
              ...
          onChangeText={emailText => {
            setEmail(emailText);
            setInlineValidations({
              ...inlineValidations,
              emailNotValid: !validateIsEmail(emailText),
            });
          }}
        />
```

In this example setEmail and setInlineValidations are state setters defined by the useState hook, example   `const [email, setEmail] = useState('');`, you can of course adapt this to your way of handling state.

Answer (score 0):

```
   isEmailValid = () => {
    const expression = /(?!.*\.{2})^([a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+(\.[a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+)*|"((([\t]*\r\n)?[\t]+)?([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7e\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))*(([\t]*\r\n)?[\t]+)?")@(([a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.)+([a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.?$/i;
    return expression.test(String(this.state.email_id).toLowerCase())
}
```