# Firebase: Email has been badly formatted

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, formik, yup

I'm using react-native, a formik form, yup validation and firebase authentication. However, I keep getting this error when I try to sign in:

> createUser error: [Error: The email address is badly formatted.]

Here's my code:
Firebase API:

```
export const signInUser = (email, password) => {
console.log('signInUser has been called')
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.trim(), password)
    .catch((error) => console.log('signIn error: ', error));
    if (email==""){
        console.log('email empty')
    } 
    if (password==""){
        console.log('password empty')
    }
    if (email=="abc@gmail.com"){
        console.log('email not empty')
    }
```

}

Sign In Screen:

```
  createUser(){
    FirebaseAPI.createUser(this.state.email, this.state.password)
  }

  signIn(){
    FirebaseAPI.signInUser(this.state.email, this.state.password)
  }
```

Form:

```
<Formik 
          initialValues={{ email: '', password:'' }} 
          onSubmit={(values: FormValues, formikBag: FormikActions<FormValues>) =>
                    this.handleSubmit(values, formikBag)}
          validationSchema= {yupObject().shape({
                    email: yupString()
                    .email("Inavlid email address")
                    .required("This field is required"),
                    password: yupString()
                      .min(8, "Password must be longer than 8 characters")
                      .required("This field is required")
                    })}
        render={(formikBag: FormikProps<FormValues>) => this.renderForm(formikBag)}
      />
```

This is the result after logging the values:

```
[09:39:16] signInUser has been called
[09:39:16] email empty
[09:39:16] password empty
[09:39:16] signIn error:  [Error: The email address is badly formatted.]
```

Logging the actual values would give no result so I opted to check if the strings were empty, and it appears that they are.
However, when I remove the formik form and use regular Input fields with no validation, everything works fine.

Comment: The error message is quite explicit: it seems `this.state.email` is not a valid email address. You might want to log that variable just before calling `createUser`.

Comment: Don't use screenshots of textual content please. Instead just add the text itself to your question and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow. Also: make sure the code in your question is updated, to show the logging statements that produce the output you shared.

Comment: It's still unclear how the code you shared where you log the values relates to the call to `firebase.auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.trim(), password)`. In in the latter you're passing an invalid value for `email.trim()`. I'd log that precise value (`console.log(email.trim())`), and see what's wrong.

Comment: I've updated the question. Thank you for that tip

Comment: That turns the question into a "How do I get the value from a Formik form?" I have no experience with Formik, but reducing the scope of the question may help attract experts in that technology.

Comment: Alright. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Validate `this.state.email` before using it. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43676695/8080186) for a similar issue.